# Is using .container mandatory with bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a Bootstrap 3 project and I am trying to understand of the use of the .container class is mandatory. I am trying to achieve a full-width page and if I use the .container it sort of creates margins on the left and right sides.

So I tried coding my page without wrapping my contents inside .container. The result is the following:

[image: without container]

But, when I wrap it all inside the .container it magically fixed itself, have a look:

[image: with container]

Any idea how I can achieve a full width age with bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As showed in [this article](http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-grid-introduction#fluid) you can create your own container instead of `.container`

```
.my-fluid-container {
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

This seems to work instead of `.container` very well with `col-*` classes inside. Maybe there are some caveats however nothing weird happens at the first glance.

[Example at plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5wSJdJNsul8KIPre4Di?p=preview)

Comment: When I view the plunker sample, there is a horizontal scroll bar in Chrome.

Comment: Just checked with Ubuntu Chrome Version 30.0.1599.0 dev No scroll bars. Which version do you use ?

Comment: OS X 10.8.4, Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5305615/stack_overflow/18317532_scrollbars.png

Comment: I'm afraid I could not reproduce. Don't own a mac. Will check later with the latest Chrome on Win and Linux. If it happens on mac only it should be reported as an issue at the bootstrap repo.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use `.row` and the `.col-*` classes then it's mandatory to use a `.container` which defines the boundaries for `.col-*` to work.

Else normal html design rules applies and you need to define your own css classes to deal with the full-width layout you're trying to achieve.

Comment: how would you resolve the full-width issue as elegantly as possible?

Comment: Well... Without an example i can't argue. :) Images are not enough. Try to create a jsfiddle of the problem. Normally it's only a matter of padding,margin,borders...

Comment: are you ok with a jade template, too?

Comment: @johnsmith to diagnose this problems the generated html is mandatory